# How do I include a custom class file in a module?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7 module development, I could include a custom inc, api, or php class file using the [file[]=](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#files) directive in the module.info file or the drupal_load_included() function.

With D8 using PSR, what is the proper way to package up a "plain ole PHP object" and reference it in `DefaultController.php`? Think something like: `$a = new POPO();`.

Is just giving the PHP file containing the class a `namespace` sufficient? How does the controller (or module in general) know to reference or scan for that class?

Comment: This link [Creating Drupal 8.x modules](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/8) might be helpful

Comment: Yes, I've read through https://www.drupal.org/node/2087879 but upon not seeing the file[]= directive, it unfortunately didn't answer this specific question of file inclusion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't use `file[] = ...` anymore. Instead, classes are autoloaded. For example, I have a module with the following file structure:

- views_hybrid/

  - views_hybrid.info.yml
  - views_hybrid.module
  - src/

    - Plugin/

      - Field/

        - FieldFormatter/

          - HybridFormatter.php

`HybridFormatter.php` defines a class called HybridFormatter.

In my .module file, if I start typing in my IDE (NetBeans in this case) `HybridFormatter` it autocompletes to `\Drupal\views_hybrid\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\HybridFormatter::` because it is autoloaded. Since I don't want that whole path littering my module, at the top I have placed the line,

```
use Drupal\views_hybrid\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\HybridFormatter;
```

along with `use` directives for other classes I am including for use with my module.

The namespace is defined in HybridFormatter.php like so:

```
namespace Drupal\views_hybrid\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

class HybridFormatter extends FormatterBase { ... }
```

Comment: So to ensure I fully understand, HybridFormatter.php will be autoloaded... automatically? There is no need for an include_once()? Does HybridFormatter.php have a namespace defined?

Comment: There is no need for `include_once` or `require_once` or anything. Hybridformatter.php does define a namespace. I'll include in the answer.

Comment: @beth Can you help me ? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233565/use-external-class-in-drupal-8-module-with-file-name-and-class-name

Answer (score 16):

I'd like to add that for including a custom class that doesn't fit into the D8 "plugin, controller, form, etc." defaults, you can still do so as noted [PSR-4 overview here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/psr-4-namespaces-and-autoloading-in-drupal-8)

For my use case, I dropped a "CustomClass.php" in /modules/custom/my_module/src/
At the beginning of the file I included the namespace declaration

```
namespace Drupal\my_module;
```

and in the file I wanted to use it in (in this particular case my_theme.theme) I added

```
use Drupal\my_module\CustomClass;
```